# Neural Network Black Box Workarounds

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, svm

I am dealing with a data set that includes rich textual data (e.g., blog entries, magazine articles, essays, book reviews, etc.) as well as a host of proprietary metrics, including numerous quantitative measures of consumer resonance.  All of the textual data is in the same language and the data set sample size is approximately 400.  There is some human pre-processing of the textual data designed to summarize roughly 10 key aspects of each textual work (these metrics do not change across the sample), and these key aspects can be either boolean, categorical, or discrete values.  Additionally, I plan on utilizing a bag-of-words algorithm across the sample to supplement the human-generated analysis just described.

I am considering utilizing a neural network to attempt to predict consumer resonance using the data described above, but it is important for me to understand relative importance of each factor.  Additionally, I expect that of the roughly 10 textual metrics, some will play a much larger role in affecting consumer resonance than others, and the importance of these may change depending on the subject content of the particular article.  For example, individuals reading an article on women's beauty or dating issues in large cities may value different things than those reading a book review in the New York Times.  I have these questions:

- Is it possible to back out this relative importance using a neural network?
- Is this data set large enough to properly train a neural network?
- Would I be better off utilizing a Bayesian tree or SVM approach, or perhaps use these in conjunction with a neural network to supplement the analysis?
- I was considering a backpropagation network, but is there a potentially more valid type I should be looking at?

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed possible to get the relative importance of features from any black box model. A way to do this is a *partial dependency plot*: Let $f$ be your black box function and $x_{i, s}$ the s'th feature of the i'th data point. Then we can look at the response of the black box where we average all other features $x_{i,-s}$ out over the data set:

$$f(x_s) = {1 \over N} \sum_i^N f(x_s, x_{i, -s}).$$

Have a look at [Greedy function approximation: a gradient boosting machine](http://docs.salford-systems.com/GreedyFuncApproxSS.pdf) by Friedman for more details.

With respect to the data size: it sounds a lot like a tough call to use neural nets for this. It depends on the data itself, but I must say that I'd rather go for a sparse linear model in your case with careful feature engineering.

Backprop is just a way to calculate the gradients of a neural net. This is what what is used in practice most of the time.

Comment: Thank you, BayerJ.  Greatly appreciate the reply.  Also, if I needed confidence intervals in addition to point estimates of the consumer resonance variable we are attempting to predict, is there a framework in place to do this using neural networks or would I simply be better off utilizing an approach like Bayesian additive regression trees or a vector space model as you indicated?

Comment: If you need a confidence interval and have that many samples I recommend you to use Gaussian processes. They are extremly capable at giving predictive distributions with the only problem that learning scales at $O(n^3)$ where $n$ is the number of samples. But this is not a problem for you here.